# IntelliJ autocomplete to replace the function name

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I've switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ and there is something which I couldn't find yet nor google:

How to get the autocomplete to replace the name of the function?
In Eclipse, it would be the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> functionality.

For example,

```
userController.setAmount();
```

suppose I would like not to call the `setAmount()` but a `setDefaultPassword()`, I place my caret after the `set` then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to autocomplete, the `setDefaultPassword()` shows up but if I press enter, it won't replace `Amount()` and I'll end up with

```
userController.setDefaultPassword();Amount();
```

So obviously what I wanted is to replace the `setAmount()` by `setDefaultPassword()`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Press Tab instead of Enter to select the item, and the identifier will be replaced. See also http://jetbrains.dzone.com/articles/top-20-code-completions-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Awesome thanks! I guess my fingers didn't find that out naturally :)

Comment: what is this feature called? I would like to search if eclipse has it as well...

Answer (score 13):

You can configure it in IntelliJ IDEA Settings under `Keymap` / `Editor Actions` / `Choose Lookup Item Replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a workaround:

1. place the cursor after `set`
2. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cursor-right</kbd>. So the characters after `set` are selected.
3. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>blank</kbd>
4. select a proposal and press <kbd>enter</kbd>