# Eclipse autocomplete to replace the function name

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, hotkeys

[IntelliJ has this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640224/intellij-autocomplete-to-replace-the-function-name) with TAB is there something like this for Eclipse? Any plugin that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when the content assist popup is active to toggle the "overwrite" mode:

[image]

Or check *Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Completion overwrites* to toggle it permanently.